What are the degress of freedom in the summary output for GLMs in R?
I am currently self-studying GLMs with the book "Generalized Additive Models An Introduction with R" and I am a bit confused regarding the degrees of freedom in the summary output for GLMs in R.
In the book, the scaled deviance is defined as
$$
D^* = 2\big(l(\hat{\beta}_{max}) - l(\hat{\beta})\big)
$$
where $\hat{\beta}_{max}$ denotes the MLE of the saturated model and $\hat{\beta}$  is the MLE of the fitted model with $p$ parameters. As we can see, this is just the generalized likelihood ratio statistic.
In general, when using the generalized likelihood ratio test to compare two models, one model with $p$ parameters and one model with $p-r$ parameters, we use the fact that the test statistic has $\chi_{r}^2$ as its asymptotic distribution.
Until now, I have assumed that the scaled deviance asymptotically follows a $\chi_{n-p}^2$-distribution and that the degrees of freedom in the summary output in R refer to $n-p$, where $n$ is the number of data points.
However, the book states that the asymptotic result for the generalized likelihood ratio statistic relies on the fact that the number of parameters in both models remain fixed, which is not the case for $D^*$ since the saturated model has as many parameters as data points available.
So my question is, if the scaled deviance does not asymptotically follow a $\chi_{n-p}^2$-distribution, what do the degrees of freedom in the summary output for GLMs refer to?
Any help is much appreciated!
